# What is gcnew?

Tags: .net, c++-cli

I stumbled across this code and am too proud to go and ask the author what it means.

```
Hashtable^ tempHash = gcnew Hashtable(iterators_);

IDictionaryEnumerator^ enumerator = tempHash->GetEnumerator();
```

What is `gcnew` and how important is it to use that instead of simply `new`? (I'm also stumped by the caret; I asked about that [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202463/what-does-the-caret-mean-in-cnet).)

Comment: You can read about some of the C++/CLI features here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B/CLI

Comment: the caret '^' acts like the '*' when declaring a managed type ie;

std::string* str;  // pointer to std::string - can be nulptr

Answer (score 87, accepted):

[gcnew](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/te3ecsc8.aspx) is for .NET reference objects; objects created with gcnew are automatically garbage-collected; it is important to use gcnew with CLR types

Comment: Out of curiosity, how important is it to use `gcnew` with CLR types? Is it okay to statically declare a CLR type (ie use `System::String` instead of `System::String^`)? Will it correctly deallocate at the end of its lifetime/scope?

Comment: @jliv902: I doubt it - but I've been out of that sphere for a while!

Answer (score 54):

`gcnew` is an operator for allocating memory, just like the `new` operator, except you don't need to `delete` anything created with it; it's ***g***arbage ***c***ollected. You use `gcnew` for creating .Net managed types, and `new` for creating unmanaged types.

Answer (score 9):

The caret '^' acts simarly to the '*' in C/C++ when declaring a type;

```
// pointer to new std::string object -> memory is not garbage-collected
std::string* strPtr = new std::string;

// pointer to System::String object -> memory is garbage-collected
System::String^ manStr = gcnew System::String;
```

I use the term 'pointer' when describing the managed object as a managed object can be compared to 'nullptr' just like a pointer in C/C++. A reference in C/C++ can not be compared to 'nullptr' as it is the address of an existing object.

Managed objects use automatic-reference-counting meaning that they are destroyed automatically when they have a reference count of zero although if two or more unreachable objects refer to eachother, you will still have a memory leak. Be warned that automatic reference counting is not free performance wise so use it wisely.