# Some questions about special operators i've never seen in C++ code

Tags: c++, syntax, c++-cli

I have downloaded the Phoenix SDK June 2008 (Tools for compilers) and when I'm reading the code of the Hello sample, I really feel lost.

```
public
ref class Hello
{
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
//
// Description:
//
//    Class Variables.
//
// Remarks:
//
//    A normal compiler would have more flexible means for holding
//    on to all this information, but in our case it's simplest (if
//    somewhat inelegant) if we just keep references to all the
//    structures we'll need to access as classstatic variables.
//
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------

static Phx::ModuleUnit                 ^ module;
static Phx::Targets::Runtimes::Runtime ^ runtime;
static Phx::Targets::Architectures::Architecture       ^ architecture;
static Phx::Lifetime                   ^ lifetime;
static Phx::Types::Table               ^ typeTable;
static Phx::Symbols::Table                ^ symbolTable;
static Phx::Phases::PhaseConfiguration        ^ phaseConfiguration;
```

2 Questions : What's that ref keyword?
What is that sign ^ ? What is it doing

protected:

```
  virtual void
  Execute
  (
     Phx::Unit ^ unit
  ) override;
```

};

override is a C++ keyword too? It's colored as such in my Visual Studio.
I really want to play with this framework, but this advanced C++ is really an obstacle right now. Thank you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's not standard C++, it's [C++/CLI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B/CLI).

Comment: I guess this is why Sun sue Microsoft years ago, to prevent this kind of "enhancements"

Comment: They're not enhancements. This is a separate language. It is not C++. Microsoft doesn't claim that it is C++. C++/CLI is technically a completely different beast.

Comment: C++/CLI just has that annoying similarity in naming, like Java and JavaScript.

Comment: And the extension is .cpp, I was totally expecting to see C++ code:( Thanks for all the answers guys!

Comment: @OscarRyz : The "sued" enhancements you're referring to can be found in the differences between C# and Java. The C++/CLI features like `ref` and `^` found in the question are there as a bridge between native code (pure C++) and managed code (extensions), and are there to make sure there's no ambiguity between what is native/pure C++ and what is managed code, thus the new keywords and operators. Please refer to http://www.gotw.ca/publications/C++CLIRationale.pdf for a complete description/rationale.

Answer (score 5):

It's a Microsoft extension for use with .NET.  The caret indicates a handle to an object stored on the managed heap.  See [Bran Bray's](http://blogs.msdn.com/branbray/archive/2003/11/17/51016.aspx) blog for a nice description.

Answer (score 5):

It is C++/CLI - code that is written to be run as managed code under the .Net framework, not regular C++ code.

- ref - this class is a reference type, it is allocated in the managed heap and will be garbage collected
- ^ - this variable is a handle to a managed instance
- override - this method overrides the base class implementation

Answer (score 4):

That is not part of standard C++. It's [C++/CLI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B/CLI), which is a Microsoft language specification designed to replace [Managed C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Managed_Extensions_for_C%2B%2B):

> C++/CLI (Common Language
>   Infrastructure) is Microsoft's
>   language specification intended to
>   supersede Managed Extensions for C++.
>   Completely revised to simplify the
>   older Managed C++ syntax (which is now
>   deprecated), it provides much more
>   clarity and code readability than
>   Managed C++. C++/CLI is standardized
>   by Ecma as ECMA-372. It is currently
>   only available in Visual Studio 2005
>   and 2008 (also included in the Express
>   Editions).

The caret symbol is the C++/CLI equivalent of a pointer, as described in Rob Walker's answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202463/what-does-the-caret-mean-in-c-cli):

> ...the caret is the managed equivalent
>   of a * (pointer) which in C++/CLI
>   terminology is called a 'handle' to a
>   'reference type' (since you can still
>   have unmanaged pointers). See this
>   [overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379617(VS.80).aspx)
>   from Microsoft.

The usage of "ref class X" instead of the familiar "class X" is discussed in this [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/hsutter/archive/2003/11/18/53509.aspx).