# What does 'System::String^' mean in C++?

Tags: .net, visual-c++, c++-cli, language-features

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does the caret mean in C++/CLI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202463/what-does-the-caret-mean-in-c-cli)

`System::String` is a class. What does the additional caret mean?

```
System::String^ productString = L"";
```

Has anyone seen this before?  I can't find anything in Stroustrop on this one.

Comment: You can't find anything because this is not C++ code. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B/CLI

Comment: Removed C++ tag because this is not C++.

Comment: The C++ tag being missing is why I couldn't find other matching answers before.

Comment: It's not exactly a duplicate. This question asks what it means **in C++**. Of course the answer is "nothing, and what you're looking at isn't actually C++", but as @Kieveli points out, if you don't already know the answer, then you're going to ask *this* question, not "what does it mean in C++/CLI"

Comment: Nice =)  I earned the popular question badge on a question with 0 up-votes.  That should be a new kind of badge.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is Microsoft's **[C++/CLI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B/CLI)**. The `^` operator is used for accessing .NET reference types. It means sort of a "handle", and the syntax is `ClassName^` instead of `ClassName*`.

Answer (score 6):

It's not really C++ but C++/CLI (a C++ look-alike language targeting the Common Language Interface)

Answer (score 6):

> What does `'System::String^'` mean in C++?

Nothing! Because it isn't C++, its C++/CLI.  `productString`  is a handle `^` to `""`

Answer (score 3):

This syntax is specific to [C++/CLI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730837%28VS.80%29.aspx), Microsoft's managed version of C++.

Avoid this unless you absolutely **must** have it for interop with native C++ code.  If you are writing managed code, use C# - native code, C++.

Answer (score 2):

It is not a standard C++, it's [C++/CLI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B/CLI) where `System::String^` means a handle to `System::String`.

Comment: No `System::String^` doesnt mean a reference to System::String. `references` are different from `handles`.