# what does the symbol ^% mean in c++ project

Tags: c++-cli

i have a c# project **AAA** with the project type “class library", in another c++ project, it add the AAA.DLL in the reference, in the source code

```
void CTest:OnCallback(OperationCallbackInfo^% oci)
```

OperationCallbackInfo is class defined in AAA.dll

my question is: what does the symbol ^ and % mean in the parameter?

Comment: @Brendan Long: It's *not* a duplicate. `^%` isn't the same as `^` on its own (though it's probably no surprise that they are related).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It means what you have isn't really C++ at all, but C++/CLI, Microsoft's proprietary version of the language for .NET.

If memory serves, `^%` is the syntax for a "tracking reference". It means (at least pretty much) the same as `ref` does in C#. From a C++ point of view, it's pretty much the same as defining a parameter as a reference to a pointer.

Comment: Not quite. The % alone signifies a tracking reference - see https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/extensions/tracking-reference-operator-cpp-component-extensions?view=msvc-160 or https://web.archive.org/web/20121129100839/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8903062a(VS.80).aspx . The '^' is a "handle", kind of like a pointer to an object on the managed heap. See https://web.archive.org/web/20150117095313/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yk97tc08(VS.80).aspx . So ^% is indeed like a reference to a pointer, where the pointer and the object pointed to are both on the managed heap.

Comment: Incidentally, if you dereference a handle (^), the result will be a tracking reference (%).

Answer (score 0):

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202463/what-does-the-caret-mean-in-c-cli), it's a "handle", which is a reference (similar to a pointer) in managed C++.

Comment: That's dealing only with `^`, which isn't quite the same as `^%`.