# What does the C++/CLI Object^% (caret percent-sign) declaration mean?

Tags: c++-cli

This apparently is a Google-proof term since I can't get any search engines to not throw away the "extra" characters. I did also look on MSDN in the C++ reference but I can't seem to find the C++/CLI reference because there is nothing in the declarations section on it.

Comment: MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8903062a%28VS.80%29.aspx  See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/202463/what-does-the-caret-mean-in-c-cli

Comment: @BlueRaja, if you answer it I'll mark it as right. I just found that link and the extra CLI section in the docs. Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [what does the symbol ^% mean in c++ project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4999575/what-does-the-symbol-mean-in-c-project)

Comment: The MSDN link in @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft 's comment above is now broken. Here's a valid archived version from the Wayback Machine: https://web.archive.org/web/20121129100839/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8903062a(VS.80).aspx

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`%` is a [tracking reference](https://web.archive.org/web/20121129100839/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8903062a(VS.80).aspx).

It is similar to a native reference (`Object&`), but a tracking reference can reference a CLR object while a native reference cannot.  The distinction is necessary because the garbage collector can move CLR objects around, so a CLR-object's memory address may change.

The `^` is a [handle](https://web.archive.org/web/20150117095313/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yk97tc08(VS.80).aspx). This simply means it is managed.  See [MSDN](https://web.archive.org/web/20150117095313/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yk97tc08(VS.80).aspx) and also [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202463/what-does-the-caret-mean-in-c-cli).

Answer (score 19):

It means "pass by reference":

```
 void bar::foo(Object^% arg) {
    arg = gcnew Object;    // Callers argument gets updated
 }
```

Same thing in C++:

```
 void foo(Object** arg) {
    *arg = new Object;
 }
```

or C#:

```
 void foo(out object arg) {
     arg = new Object();
 }
```

C++/CLI doesn't distinguish between *ref* and *out*, it does not have the *definite assignment* checking feature that the C# language has so no need to distinguish between the two.  Same in VB.NET, ByRef vs ByVal.

Answer (score 10):

Essentially, it's the "managed" version of `Object*&`, and equivalent to `ref` or `out` on a reference type in C#.

Answer (score 3):

This is a managed pointer by reference.  So if you had something like:

```
void DoSomething(System::String^% stringObject)
```

in C# it would look like:

```
void DoSomething(ref System.String stringObject)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a [C++/CLI Tracking Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/extensions/tracking-reference-operator-cpp-component-extensions?view=msvc-160).  This is kind of like a C++ reference, but to a managed object.