# What is the meaning of this strange syntax

Tags: visual-studio, syntax, c++-cli

Today I saw the following syntax. Can anybody tell me the meaning of this:

```
System::ComponentModel::Container ^components;
```

I got this code in Visual C++, after I used a wizard to create a service.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does the caret mean in C++/CLI?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/202463/what-does-the-caret-mean-in-c-cli)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `^` operator (not to be confused with the binary XOR operator) is specific to C++/CLI.

It is used to declare a handle to a .NET managed object.

A handle is a reference to the object which differs from traditional C++ pointers in the fact that it allows Garbage Collection to function correctly for the referenced object, making manual object deletion unnecessary.

This syntax supersedes the managed C++ extensions'  `__gc` pointers.

More details can be found here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B/CLI

Answer (score 4):

It is C++/CLI handle. C++/CLI is Microsoft's managed extension to C++ to provide compatibility with .NET CLR.

[Read here a little bit more about C++/CLI](http://www.google.cz/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CCMQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.codeproject.com%2FKB%2Fmcpp%2Fquickcppcli.aspx&ei=pbJbTeK6IsKbOrGJ6e4L&usg=AFQjCNE0ms_bAD6cSjF4j_QNPycyXLAOuw&sig2=1Fryo-hFRBWQl086MaGFUQ).

Answer (score 1):

This is managed C++, which is not C++.

The line defines a variable components which is a *managed* pointer to System::ComponentModel::Container