# c++/cli caret^ Vs. Pointer*?

Tags: pointers, c++-cli

I've programming for a long time in C and in C#, I thought moving to C++ would be smooth...
anyway, I've seen the use of caret but I don't understand the meaning of it.

what's the different between:

```
std::string *st1;
```

to

```
String::string ^st2;
```

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does the caret mean in C++/CLI?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/202463/what-does-the-caret-mean-in-c-cli)

Comment: @HansPassant, I saw the question you referring to. but they just say it's like a pointer. I know it's like that, I don't know what's the different between them.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The caret is specific to [C++/CLI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B/CLI), Microsoft's .NET version of C++, where it is [the managed equivalent of a pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202463/what-does-the-caret-mean-in-c-cli).

It is not actually part of standard C++, so unless you truly mean to use .NET, don't use it.

Answer (score 2):

```
String::string ^st2
```

is not a standard ANSI C++ syntax!

Comment: Thanks, the tags were fixed to C++cli.