# error of "cannot use this indirection on type" with vector

Tags: .net, visual-c++, c++-cli

I'm simply trying to declare a vector:

```
std::vector<ListViewItem^> itemsVector;
```

I have used `#include <vector>`, but it works only for primitive types and does not work for `ListViewItem`.

getting the error:

> cannot use this indirection on type

Comment: try change it to `std::vector<ListViewItem>`.

Comment: @varnie works for type int for instance , but not for ListViewItem , any idea why?

tried also std::vector<ListViewItem^> itemsVector; but no good

Comment: Please ask in the question.

Comment: In C++ pointers have asterisks so it's better to use them instead of caret.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8701282/c-caret-vs-pointer

Comment: @harper thanks , I added it to my question , id you can help here I would appreciate it

Comment: That ain't no `C++` but `C++/CLI`.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using C++/CLI, then you should generally use .Net containers to contain .Net objects. When writing C++/CLI, I generally only use C++ containers in code where I need to call into regular C++ code (and the contained items must all be straight C++ objects too).

```
List<ListViewItem^>^ itemsList = gcnew List<ListViewItem^>();
```

As pointed out in the comments, you will probably want to add the following line at the top of your file if you don't already have them (I assumed you already had these).

```
using namespace System;
using namespace System::Collections::Generic;
```

Comment: what should I declare for List ? i'm getting undeclared identifier error

Comment: Namespace issues probably: The class is `System::Collections::Generic::List<>`, so if you're not in a header file you can add a `using namespace System::Collections::Generic;`