# What does ^ mean in Visual Studio C++?

Tags: visual-studio, c++-cli

Microsoft's documentation often makes use of `^` in places where I would expect either a `*` or `&`.

Example:

```
public:
event UnhandledExceptionEventHandler^ UnhandledException {
    virtual void add(UnhandledExceptionEventHandler^ value) sealed;
    virtual void remove(UnhandledExceptionEventHandler^ value) sealed;
}
```

The use of `^`  really puzzles me.

Comment: What research have you done?

Comment: trivial duplicate of [c++ caret^ Vs. Pointer\*?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8701282/c-caret-vs-pointer) or [What does the caret (‘^’) mean in C++/CLI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202463/what-does-the-caret-mean-in-c-cli)

Comment: That's not standard C++ if that is what you are asking. That is probably some managed C++-CLI flavor with its grammar and set of rules.

Comment: @nicomp I read as much documentation as I could find on microsoft's site. I had no idea they where talking about C++/CLI since the documentation only talks about C++ with no indication that it's an entirely different language.

Answer (score 2):

That is either C++/CX or C++/CLI, and the `^` indicates a reference of some sort--either a pointer to a managed reference type or handle.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2012/09/17/ccx-part-2-of-n-types-that-wear-hats/

[In C++/CLI, what does the hat character ^ do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500580/in-c-cli-what-does-the-hat-character-do)

Comment: So, the `^`, is just MS's way of writing `&`?

Comment: Doesn't the answer say clearly that it's not that simple, and don't those links explain clearly what it really does?