# What does ^ (caret) mean in C++, as in String^

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does the caret mean in C++/CLI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202463/what-does-the-caret-mean-in-c-cli)

What does `^` mean in this example?

```
String^ dd= Convert::ToString(DateTime::Now);
```

or `array<String^,2>^` or  `OleDbCommand^` and so on ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is not C++, but either Managed C++, C++/CLI, or WinRT. In all of those instances, this notation stands for a managed reference.

Answer (score 0):

`^` means its a managed C++ entity. C++/CLI.

Answer (score 0):

.NET managed pointer, a specific Visual C++ extension.

Comment: It is actually a different language, [C++/CLI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B/CLI).