# Difference between System::String^ and System::String

Tags: .net, c++-cli

What is actually the difference between `System::String^ ex;` and `System::String ex1;`?
I found out that the one with "^" means that it is top-level. But what does that mean?

Comment: One is a tracked reference, one is not.

Comment: “top level”? What’s that supposed to mean?

Comment: To the people who closed this as a duplicate, please revert. One isn’t a duplicate, and one is age old and uses outdated / wrong terminology.

Comment: The term 'top level' is used in several compiler messages. For example, `gcnew String^()` gives a compiler error of `error C3698: 'System::String ^' : cannot use this type as argument of 'gcnew' did you mean 'System::String' (without the top-level '^')?`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`System::String^` is a reference to a managed string object, `System::String` is a managed string object directly on the stack or inline in another class.

As mentioned in [What does the caret (‘^’) mean in C++/CLI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202463/what-does-the-caret-mean-in-c-cli), the `^` is a tracking reference, roughly equivalent to `*` for a pointer in unmanaged code. In the same way you can have `unmanagedClass* foo1;` and `unmanagedClass foo2;`, you can have `System::String^ str1;` and `System::String str2;`

When used without the `^`, it follows the same rules as an unmanaged class without the `*`: Access methods on it with a `.` not a `->`. Automatically cleaned up when it leaves scope (destructor in unmanaged, dispose method in managed).

One thing that does make working with managed objects without their `^` harder is that most managed objects don't define a copy constructor or the equals operator. Neither of those would be used in C# or VB, so they generally aren't implemented. Without them, it's impossible to assign a new value to a variable without a `^`, so you're generally limited to constructing just a single object.

Answer (score 1):

C++/CLI has a feature called ["stack semantics"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177191.aspx).  It is meant to emulate the RAII pattern in C++, the compiler automatically emits a call to the destructor of the class when you declare a local variable of a reference type without the ^ hat.

This is not appropriate for the System::String class, it doesn't have a destructor.

Since it also doesn't have any useful constructors, you'll almost always just end up with a compiler error message when you try to declare it without the hat anyway.  Always use the hat.