# C++/CLI handle operator

Tags: visual-c++, c++-cli

I am just curious about C++/CLI handle(^) and how it works. For e.g:

The first thing that I cannot understand is, [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202463/what-does-the-caret-mean-in-c-cli) the accepted answer says that the caret is the managed equivalent of a * (pointer). However, unlike *, I can directly assign value to ^.

```
int ^num;
num = 4;
```

This would not work in C++:

```
int *num2;
num2 = new int[1];
num2 = 10;
```

Why is this behavior observed?
Also, in Microsoft [Webpage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/yk97tc08.aspx) they say you cannot point to a member of the object, and it does not support pointer arithmetic. So both the following code snippet would fail to compile

```
int ^num3 = gcnew int[10];

for(int i = 0; i<10; i++)
    %(num3 + i) = i
```

or

```
for(int i = 0; i<10; i++)
    (num3 + i) = i
```

Why???

That brings me to final question: What would be equivalent of following int native/normal C++ code snippet in C++/CLI?

```
int *array1;
array1 = new int[ 10];

for( int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
     *(array1 + i ) = i;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`^` is the equivalent of `*`, for the purposes of dealing with class objects (new/gcnew, passing as parameters, storing as part of a class definition, etc). Pointer arithmetic isn't the same in C++/CLI.

Here's the equivalent to your code snippet:

```
array<int>^ array1;
array1 = gcnew array<int>(10);

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    array1[i] = i;
```

`array<int>^`: This is a managed reference, stored on the stack.

`array1 = gcnew array<int>(10)`: This is creating a managed object (from the class named "array") on the managed heap, and assigning the reference to the local variable on the stack.

`array1[i] = i`: Behind the scenes, this calls a method on the "array" class, passing it the index and the new value (both `i` in this case).

Answer (score 4):

`int^` means a reference to a **[boxed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk.aspx)** integer.
It's not a pointer to a regular integer.

A handle to a reference type in CLR isn't equivalent to a pointer. It is similar.

Both "point" at an object, but that's about where the similarity ends.
It's much more like a C++ **[shared_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr)**.

Anyway, a boxed integer is an object that wraps an integer number.
`int^` is a a reference to a boxed object, so besides holding a value, it can be null (because it's a reference).

when you do `int^ = 4;` the boxed object's constructor construct a boxed object with the value of 4.
So unlike a c++ pointer, you're not pointing a the address "4" you're "pointing" at an object that happens to contain the value 4.

Comment: Can you please explain me the difference between boxed integer and regular integer?

Comment: @Dwight : Microsoft paid people to write documentation, SO is made up of volunteers – read the documentation _first_ before asking the unpaid people to take time explaining something that is already readily available. ;-] [Boxing (C++/CLI)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh875061.aspx)

Comment: @Dwight : I've added some explanation. Read the links anyway.

Comment: @Yochai Timmer: Thanks for comprehensive explanation for boxed integer