# Returning value from my function in C++/cli is always 1

Tags: c++, function, command-line-interface

I've got this code (Simplified example) in my Visual Studio 10:

```
int myfunc(void)
{
    array <int^>^ temparr=gcnew array<int^>(11);

    for (int i=0; i<11; i++)
    {
         temparr[i]=0;
    }

    temparr[2]=1;  //one of the elements is 1


    for (int i=0; i<11; i++)
    {
         if (!temparr[i]) return 0;   
    }  

    return 1;
}
```

But when I use this function the output is 1 rather than 0. What can be the problem and how to correct this code?

Comment: FYI, `^` (hat) indicates a managed handle (i.e. garbage collected object).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Array of value type (`int` here) should look like this:

```
array<int>^ temparr = gcnew array<int>(11);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dtbydz1t%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You have undefined behavior in your code, where you assign integer values to garbage-collected pointers. Why would you even want that? Instead declare `temparr` as

```
array <int> temparr(11);
```

I.e. an array of normal integer values.

Answer (score 2):

Your code does not do what you think it does.

Instead of assigning values to an array of integer, you are assigning them to an array of [pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202463/what-does-the-caret-mean-in-c-cli)...

A simple array of integer will solve your problem:

```
array <int> temparr(11);
//    ^^^^^        ^^^^
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But an error occurred after declaring such array: Error C3149: (type) : cannot use this type here without a top-level (char).

And after all i have a managed code with managed array. It needs to compare two arrays - managed and unmanaged. Is it possible?