# What it mean: String^ name

Tags: string, c++-cli, clr, difference

What does this mean: `String^ var_name` ? I can do this only in CLR C/C++. And I know that `^` is a XOR.

What is the difference between:

```
`string name` and `String^ name`?
```

Comment: In the context of CLR and C++/CLI, `^` is not XOR, it's a managed reference (or something like that, I don't really know this MS stuff).

Comment: It would be nice if some answer pointed out that `String^ name` isn't C++.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does the caret (‘^’) mean in C++/CLI?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/202463/what-does-the-caret-mean-in-c-cli)

Answer (score 2):

It is the handle to object operator. It declares a managed pointer.

They seem like normal pointers but you don't have to free them.

From [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/yk97tc08.aspx):

> The handle declarator (`^`, pronounced "hat"), modifies the type specifier to mean that **the declared object should be automatically deleted** when the system determines that the object is no longer accessible.
>
> **A variable that is declared with the handle declarator behaves like a pointer to the object.**

Answer (score 1):

It's a managed pointer, i.e. a pointer which is garbage collected. Think of them as normal pointers, but you don't have to free them.

You have to use `gcnew` to allocate those pointers explicitly, not `new`.

Answer (score 0):

String^ is managed string. ^ operator means that variable is an managed reference.

Answer (score 0):

It is actually a heap pointer /handle to managed heap object. It is a pointer or index with no visible type attached to it.

Check these links out. 
[Heap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/481fa11f%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) , [How to Declare Handle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/481fa11f%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: I understand. Is a pointer with "garbage-collector", That don't reference other something, only himself.