# Meaning of '^' with class name in Cpp

Tags: c++-cli, managed-c++

I was reading some code in cpp and I found some code like

```
<classname>^ instancename
```

. what is its use??

I tried searching but did not get any answers.

Comment: That looks like a bitwise exclusive OR to me. Can you show more context for where you saw this?

Comment: This is a thing from Microsoft's "Managed C++" (which is a sort of hybrid between C++ and C#). I believe they no longer encourage its use, preferring you to use C#.

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/202463/what-does-the-caret-mean-in-c-cli

Comment: This article explains it in some more detail: http://www.i-programmer.info/programming/cc/921-getting-started-with-managed-c.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It represents a managed pointer, ^ points to a garbage collected object (handled by the framework).

You can check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cxx6f46y.aspx) for more details

> In Visual C++ 2002 and Visual C++ 2003, __gc * was used to declare a
>   managed pointer. This is replaced with a ^ in Visual C++ 2005, for
>   example ArrayList^ al = gcnew ArrayList();.

They are also allocated differently for example:

```
NativeObject* n = new NativeObject();
ManagedObject^ m = gcnew ManagedObject();
```

Also check this **[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yk97tc08.aspx)** for more details

This sample shows how to create an instance of a reference type on the managed heap. This sample also shows that you can initialize one handle with another, resulting in two references to same object on managed, garbage-collected heap. Notice that assigning nullptr (C++ Component Extensions) to one handle does not mark the object for garbage collection.

```
// mcppv2_handle.cpp
// compile with: /clr
ref class MyClass {
public:
   MyClass() : i(){}
   int i;
   void Test() {
      i++;
      System::Console::WriteLine(i);
   }
};

int main() {
   MyClass ^ p_MyClass = gcnew MyClass;
   p_MyClass->Test();

   MyClass ^ p_MyClass2;
   p_MyClass2 = p_MyClass;

   p_MyClass = nullptr;
   p_MyClass2->Test();   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The **handle declarator** (`^`, pronounced `"hat"`, [C++/CLI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B/CLI) terminology), modifies the type specifier to mean that the declared object should be automatically deleted when the system determines that the object is no longer accessible.

**A variable that is declared with the handle declarator behaves like a pointer to the object.** However, the variable points to the entire object, cannot point to a member of the object, and it does not support pointer arithmetic. Use the indirection operator (`*`) to access the object, and the arrow member-access operator (`->`) to access a member of the object.

Check out [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yk97tc08.aspx) and [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/202463/2589776) for more info.