# Difference between String and String ^?

Tags: .net, string, visual-c++, c++-cli

I have edited this question to make myself clear.
My question was.

If we define

String a

we can define characters as a[],

but if we define String ^ a

a[] cant be defined.

So why a[] is not defined if both are strings.

Comment: It's handle to object operator. It has to be created with `gcnew`.

Comment: [What does the caret (‘^’) mean in C++/CLI?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/202463/what-does-the-caret-mean-in-c-cli)

Comment: std::string is not spelled with a capital letter.  System::String is the .NET string type, it has the ^ hat because it is a garbage collected object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

String^ is a handle to underlying string. These are much like pointers/references in C++ except the aid they provide to garbage collector. That means you don't need to delete memory for them as you do for pointers in C++.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft's Managed C++ is radically different from the standard definitions you are used to in usual C++. One major difference is the way it handles memory allocation/freeing using **managed pointers**. The `^` you are referring to is called the *hat operator* and it is used to denote a pointer whose memory state is *managed* automatically at run-time. This means you will not have to use `delete` to free memory previously allocated for it.

While the usefulness/efficiency of the hat operator is disputed, it remains the standard way to manage memory in your case of Visual C++ .NET.