# C++ bitwise exclusive OR operator

Tags: c++

I was reading Microsoft documentation and came across bitwise exclusive OR operator. Could someone explain what does operator ^ represents in code below? I assume it is not a pointer as it would be * rather than ^.

```
private:
        Windows::Web::Http::HttpClient^ httpClient;
        Windows::Web::Http::HttpResponseMessage^ response;
```

Comment: I think you found c++/CLI code. Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/202463/what-does-the-caret-mean-in-c-cli

Comment: That's a managed pointer, not a bitwise-XOR. See linked dupe.

Comment: That is not the XOR operator and the language is not C++.

Comment: @RSahu Microsoft says it is C++ Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/dn440594

Comment: @Stealth, It is "managed C++", not "standard C++".

Comment: @AdamF - Thank you, that link explaines everything. @R Sahu - You are right

Comment: @Stealth: Microsoft is lying. :)