# difference between * and ^ in c++\c?

Tags: pointers, c++-cx

I have this code:

```
DispatcherTimer^ CalenderClock();
```

When I use `*` instead of `^` visual studio tells me:

```
an ordinary pointer to C++\CX mapping ref class or inteface class is not allowed
```

what is the difference between `^` and `*` pointers?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does the caret (‘^’) mean in C++/CLI?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/202463/what-does-the-caret-mean-in-c-cli)

Comment: see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yk97tc08.aspx

Comment: These are CLI handles, the duplicate question has some explanation as to the difference between the two.

Comment: I suspect that ^ is a Visual C++ extension to the standard C++ language.

Comment: thanks guys, now I got the difference between * and ^

Comment: What is c++\c ?

Comment: These comments are drastically inaccurate, C++/CX generates pure native code.  Consider using the [visual-c++] tag to ask questions about the Microsoft compiler in the future, better odds you'll find someone that knows what you are talking about.

Answer (score 2):

> The handle-to-object operator ^ is known as a "hat" and is fundamentally a C++ smart pointer. The memory it points to is automatically destroyed when the last hat goes out of scope or is explicitly set to `nullptr`.

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cppcx/ref-classes-and-structs-c-cx (Found by googling your error message.)

Note that this syntax is non-standard. It is a Microsoft extension to the C++ language.