# Getting error C2440 when trying SqlConnection

Tags: winforms, visual-c++, c++-cli

Getting

> Error C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from 
>   'System::Data::SqlClient::SqlConnection' to 
>   'System::Data::SqlClient::SqlConnection ^'

for this line

```
    SqlConnection^ con = SqlConnection("c:\\project\\project\\database.db");
```

Would like to know why i'm getting this error and how to fix it, im using visual c++, winform ui

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message should make clear exactly what is going wrong. You just have to look carefully, because it's a difference of a single character. Here it is again, with noise removed:

> cannot convert from 'SqlConnection' to 'SqlConnection ^'

See that `^` character at the end? The compiler is saying it can't convert from an object (`SqlConnection`) to a managed pointer-to-object (`SqlConnection^`).

To create a managed pointer-to-object, you would use the `gcnew` operator:

```
SqlConnection^ con = gcnew SqlConnection("c:\\project\\project\\database.db");
```

Or, if you don't actually need a pointer, just change the type of the `con` variable:

```
SqlConnection con = SqlConnection("c:\\project\\project\\database.db");
```

For more details, see: [What does the caret (‘^’) mean in C++/CLI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202463/what-does-the-caret-mean-in-c-cli)

Comment: ah yes, my bad i didn't notice i missed gcnew, somehow, anyways thanks for pointing it out