# C++ ^ operator used with a function

Tags: c++, xor

I am unable to search for this use case on Google or the docs:

For example:

```
typedef int (^ myStruct) (int a, bool b, double c);
```

What does the above mean? Specifically the xor (^) operator above.

Comment: It is not C++. Maybe it  is C++/CLI

Comment: This seem to be managed C++, not standard

Comment: This appears to be *managed* C++ (or C++/CLI); see [What does the caret (‘^’) mean in C++/CLI?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/202463/10871073).

Comment: Also there are no operators here. This line is a declaration  . Operators combine sub-expression(s) to form a larger expression

Comment: Edited duplicate list to link to C++/CLI instead of Objective C  (based on the C++ tag given by OP)