# What is the difference between "= gcnew MyClass()" and "= %MyClass()"?

Tags: c++-cli

What is the difference between

```
MyClass ^myClass = gcnew MyClass();
```

and

```
MyClass ^myClass = %MyClass();
```

if any?

Both seem to work, but not sure what happens behind the scenes.

Comment: Not at all the same, the 2nd statement is a broken way to use "stack semantics".  Normally written as `MyClass myClass;`, intentionally omitting the ^ hat.  The big, big difference is that the object is automatically disposed at the end of the scope block.  If you're familiar with C++ then it is the equivalent of RAII.  If you're familiar with C# then it the is the equivalent of the `using` statement.  Start googling, this is important, query for "c++/cli stack semantics".

Comment: @HansPassant thanks for the more expert insight.  I tried to reason about the problem from the c++-cli documentation online, but I am no expert.  Your response is more useful and accurate.

Comment: @HansPassant Thank you. On [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/dotnet/cpp-stack-semantics-for-reference-types?view=vs-2019) Microsoft says that the compiler does internally create the instance on the garbage collected heap (using gcnew), but does not create copy constructors. So "MyClass myClass = MyClass();" does not work unless I implement a copy constructor, however "MyClass ^myClass = %MyClass();" does work... So I guess my related question is... why?

Comment: To clarify further the above: I thought "MyClass ^myClass = %MyClass();" can be also written as "MyClass mc = MyClass(); MyClass ^myClass = %mc;" but it does not seem to be the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Revision:**

[Stack Semantics](https://www.codeproject.com/Messages/2716494/Re-What-is-stack-semantics.aspx)

---

**Previous:**
So, in both cases a newly created object's address is assigned to a pointer.  For this reason, the two statements appear to work the same.

**The Difference:**
Using `gcnew` allocates memory of a managed type (reference), that has garbage collection.

Using `%MyClass()` is analogous to using `&MyClass()`, which does not have garbage collection.

**gcnew:**
Memory for a managed type (reference or value type) is allocated by gcnew, and deallocated by using garbage collection.

**%MyClass():**
Like standard C++, this object will not be garbage collected.  Operator overloading works analogously to standard C++. Every * becomes a ^, every & becomes an %.

**Meaning of '^':**
The handle declarator (^, pronounced "hat"), modifies the type specifier to mean that the declared object should be automatically deleted when the system determines that the object is no longer accessible.

**Relevant Links:**
[Meaning of `'%'`, Search "Operator Overloading"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B/CLI)
[Meaning of `gcnew`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202459/what-is-gcnew)
[Meaning of `'^'`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202463/what-does-the-caret-mean-in-c-cli)